# Custom action to set a property after a failed RegistrySearch is not running

Tags: wix

The aim is that if the value isn't found in the registry then I want to assign a default value and then have that value display as the default value in a field in the installer UI. The default value I actually want to use is [ComputerName] but obviously I can't use [ComputerName] directly in the property value attribute because it will give me errors on compiling, specifically:

> warning CNDL1077: The 'MYPROPERTY' Property contains '[ComputerName]'
>   in its value which is an illegal reference to another property.  If
>   this value is a string literal, not a property reference, please
>   ignore this warning.  To set a property with the value of another
>   property, use a CustomAction with Property and Value attributes.

I want to get it working with plain text before I even try [ComputerName] but so far I can't even get that working.

In my project I have a Product.wxs file which contains the Product element, lots of custom actions (most of which are running fine but they're all running significantly later) and the following elements which are not cooperating and which are all siblings under the Product element.

**Property definition and registry search:**

```
<Property Id="MYPROPERTY" Value="ADefaultValue">
    <RegistrySearch Id="MyProperty" Type="raw" Root="HKLM" Win64="$(var.Win64)"
                  Key="Software\MyCompany\MyApplication" Name="MyProperty" />
</Property>
```

**Custom action definition:**

```
<CustomAction Id="SetMyPropertyDefault" Property="MYPROPERTY" Value="MyCustomValue" Execute="immediate"/>
```

**Custom action execution:**

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="SetMyPropertyDefault" After="AppSearch"><![CDATA[MYPROPERTY="ADefaultValue"]]></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

It just will not work for me at all.

For the custom element content I have tried:

```
<Custom Action="SetMyPropertyDefault" After="AppSearch"><![CDATA[MYPROPERTY="ADefaultValue"]]></Custom>

<Custom Action="SetMyPropertyDefault" After="AppSearch">1</Custom> // I thought this would always run the custom action.

<Custom Action="SetMyPropertyDefault" After="AppSearch">NOT MYPROPERTY</Custom> // Back when I wasn't using the default value on the property at all.
```

The result is always the same, I'm still getting "ADefaultValue" showing up in the UI, never the alternate "MyCustomValue".

According to every blog and SO post I've seen I'm doing exactly what I should be doing except clearly I'm missing something.
Any ideas?

---

**UPDATE/Answer:**

The piece of information that I was missing which was provided by @sutarmin-anton was that InstallUISequence runs before InstallExecuteSequence (seems counter-intuitive to me but there you go).
But as it happened I didn't need to explicitly duplicate the custom action call in each of the install sequence elements, instead I used the SetProperty element.
So now I've got the following in my Product.wxs as children of the Product element:

```
<Property Id="MYPROPERTY">
    <RegistrySearch Id="MyProperty" Type="raw" Root="HKLM" Win64="$(var.Win64)" Key="Software\MyCompany\MyApplication" Name="MyProperty" />
</Property>

<SetProperty Id="MYPROPERTY" After="AppSearch" Value="[ComputerName]">NOT MYPROPERTY</SetProperty>
```

It now runs the [SetProperty](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.windows.devel.wix.user/51814) after AppSearch in both InstallUISequence and InstallExecuteSequence, but the second time it runs the NOT MYPROPERTY will come out false so it doesn't get reset, and of course if it's run in quiet mode it'll still work correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you going through installer UI, installation is in InstallUISequence. InstallExecuteSequence runs after all UI events. This is cause of you have not seen "MyCustomValue". To change your property before UI sequence you should place your custom action in "InstallUISequence".

By the way, why don't you set default value of your property to "MyCustomValue"? Then, if AppSearch wont find value in regisrty, it just leave default value that you are trying to set manually.

Comment: Thanks @sutarmin-anton. Moving it to InstallUISequence worked alright, but my understanding of that section is that it won't run at all if the installer is being run in quiet mode. I need to support quiet mode so although this does make the custom action run, it unfortunately doesn't cover what I need for my scenario.

Comment: @Nanhydrin, I just told what you can do to see changed property in UI. For your scenario you can either duplicate custom action in InstallUISeq and InstallExecSeq or set default value of your property to "MyCustomValue". Is second case you may don't to use custom action at all.

Comment: I'm just using MyCustomValue as a simple test case. What I actually want to use as the default value is the [ComputerName] parameter, but it doesn't seem to be possible to use that directly as the property default value and I apparently have to use a custom action to be able to set the default value to the property. But I see what you mean about the order, I didn't realise the UI one ran first, so I'd need to put my custom action in both as you say.

Answer (score 1):

You may be overcomplicating things. The MYPROPERTY value will not be set at all if you don't set a default. So then you call your CA to set it if 'NOT MYPROPERTY'

I see that you've tried this, and I'd say it's the correct approach that I'd try to diagnose rather than try something else. A verbose log would be invaluable. Do a:

msiexec /i [path to msi] /l*vx [path to a text log file]

and see what CA is called, what AppSearch does, property values etc.

Your original comment of "I can't use [ComputerName] - if that's the problem why not tell us what happened and maybe there is a solution that doesn't require all this. What's the compile error, for example?

Comment: Thanks @phildw, I updated my question with the original compile error, but that was what told me to use the custom action in the first place. I had the logging on already, I'd only clocked that my custom action wasn't running but I hadn't understood why but now I understand that it's because the custom action was in the wrong sequence for how I was running it.